# Passing constant reference to an object C++

Tags: c++

this is my code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream> 
#include <cstring>  

using namespace std;

class GeneralMatrix {
public:
    GeneralMatrix(const string & n, int nr, int nc);
    GeneralMatrix * add (const GeneralMatrix&);
    const double get(int row, int col){}
    void set(int row, int col, double val){}
};

GeneralMatrix * GeneralMatrix::add(const GeneralMatrix& m2){
if (height != m2.height || width != m2.width) {
            throw "Matrix sizes must match!";
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                double val = m2.get(i, j);// Error
                if (val != 0) {
                    val += get(i, j);
                    set(i, j, val);
                }
            }
        }   
} 

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    GeneralMatrix* a ;
    GeneralMatrix* b ;
    (*a).add(*b);
    return 0;
}
```

My program produce this error when i call add function

```
main.cpp:78:41: error: passing ‘const GeneralMatrix’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘const double GeneralMatrix::get(int, int)’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
                 double val = m2.get(i, j);
```

So the problem is with constant argument but i cant figure out why . get method is constant and does not change object at all same as add method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the object (or the reference you use to access it) is constant, then you can only call constant member functions on it. `get` isn't constant, but almost certainly should be:

```
double get(int row, int col) const {}
                             ^^^^^
```

It's usually not a good idea to make a return value constant, so I removed that `const`.